Exposing Handlebars via Webpack
I want to expose jQuery and Handlebars to be accessible from the outside (i.e. browser console via window.Handlebars).
So I added expose-loader and the following module rules into the Webpack config:
…
        {
          test: require.resolve("jquery"),
          loader: "expose-loader",
          options: {
            exposes: [
              {
                globalName: "$",
                override: true
              },
              {
                globalName: "jQuery",
                override: true
              }
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          test: require.resolve("handlebars"),
          loader: "expose-loader",
          options: {
            exposes: ["Handlebars"]
          },
        },
…

and while this works perfectly for jQuery, it doesn't seem to work for Handlebars at all.
I'm not even getting any helpful error messages.
It's just not exposed.
What am I missing here?
Here you can find the full configuration:


const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (env, argv) {
  const mode = argv.mode || 'development';
  return {
    mode: mode,
    devtool: mode === 'development' ? 'source-map' : false,
    entry: {
      application: {
        import: './source/scripts/application.js',
        dependOn: ['jquery', 'handlebars']
      },
      only_form: './source/scripts/only_form.js',
      modernizr: './source/scripts/modernizr-3.6.0.js',
      jquery: './source/scripts/jquery-3.7.1.js',
      sticky: './source/scripts/sticky.min.js',
      fontdetect: './source/scripts/fontdetect.js',
      plugins: './source/scripts/plugins.js',
      waypoints: './source/scripts/waypoints.min.js',
      counterup: './source/scripts/jquery.counterup.min.js',

      application_css: './source/content/application.css.sass',
      only_form_css: './source/content/only_form.css.sass',
      print_only_form_css: './source/content/print_only_form.css.sass',
      modules_css: './source/content/modules.css.sass',
      print_css: './source/content/print.css.sass',
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.tmp/dist'),
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'scripts/[name].js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sassOptions: {
                  importer: globImporter(),
                  includePaths: require('bourbon').includePaths,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'content/images/[name][ext]'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'content/fonts/[name][ext]'
          }
        },
        {
          test: require.resolve("jquery"),
          loader: "expose-loader",
          options: {
            exposes: [
              {
                globalName: "$",
                override: true
              },
              {
                globalName: "jQuery",
                override: true
              }
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          test: require.resolve("handlebars"),
          loader: "expose-loader",
          options: {
            exposes: [
              {
                globalName: "Handlebars",
                override: true
              }
            ]
          },
        },
        {
          test: require.resolve('./source/scripts/application.js'),
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'expose-loader',
              options: {
                exposes: {
                  globalName: 'Internal',
                  moduleLocalName: 'Internal',
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        }
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [{
          from: 'source/content',
          to: 'content',
          globOptions: {
            ignore: [
              '**/_remodal.css',
              '**/*.eot',
              '**/*.gif',
              '**/*.ico',
              '**/*.jpg',
              '**/*.png',
              '**/*.sass',
              '**/*.scss',
              '**/*.svg',
              '**/*.ttf',
              '**/*.woff',
              '**/cookieconsent.css',
              '**/fonts/**',
              '**/images/**',
              '**/modules.css',
              '**/only_form.css',
              '**/print_only_form.css',
              '**/print.css',
              '**/slick.css',
            ]
          }
        }]
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: (chunkData) => ({ chunk }) => {
          return `content/${chunk.name.replace('_css', '.css')}`;
        },
      }),

      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.$": "jquery",
        Handlebars: 'handlebars',
        "window.Handlebars": 'handlebars',
        Placeholders: 'placeholder',
        root: 'window',
        "$.deparam": 'deparam',
      }),
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimize: mode === 'production',
      minimizer: [
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
        new TerserPlugin({
          extractComments: false,
        }),
      ],
    },
  }
};



PS: I also asked this on GitHub discussions without any success
